# How does svelte store set function work with bound objects?

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I need to create a svelte store with custom logic so I have adapted the code [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Svelte_stores#how_to_implement_a_store_contract_the_theory) to create a simple store with a subscribe and set function.

However, when I initialise the store as an object and create a two-way binding to one of the store's keys, the set function seems to be called with `value` already set to the `newValue` which was just passed into the store. This does not happen when the store is created with a primitive.

How can I compare the new value of the store to the current value before the new value is set? I have set up a REPL [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/9ebb9ab5c9a64e9da52df87724adf563?version=3.42.6).

```
<script>

const writable = (initialValue) => {
  let value = initialValue; // content of the store
  let subs = []; // subscriber's handlers

  const subscribe = (handler) => {
    handler(value); // call handler with current value
    subs = [...subs, handler]; // add handler to the array of subscribers
    return () => subs = subs.filter((sub) => sub !== handler); // return unsubscribe function
  };

  const set = (newValue) => {
    // This does not seem to work properly for objects
    console.log(`value: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
    console.log(`new value: ${JSON.stringify(newValue)}`);
    console.log(newValue == value); // compare new value to old value
    
    value = newValue; // update value
    subs.forEach((sub) => sub(value)); // update subscribers
  };

  return {subscribe, set}; // store contract
};

let numberStore = writable("5");
let objectStore = writable({foo: "bar"});

</script>

<p>{$numberStore}</p>
<input bind:value={$numberStore}>

<p>{JSON.stringify($objectStore)}</p>
<input bind:value={$objectStore.foo}>
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel when Svelte already provides store implementations?

Comment: The following paragraph of the mentioned tutorial *"Usually you don't implement stores from scratch; instead you'd use the writable store to create [custom stores](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-stores) with domain-specific logic"*

Comment: I want to implement custom logic in the 'set' function to write local changes to a database. As far as I can see, there is no way to do this other that creating a store from scratch.

Comment: There often is no need to; you can usually just create a regular readable/writable store, subscribe to it to add your custom logic and return the store (or parts of it).

Comment: I think @H.B. answered your main question, I just added an example of a old/new value custom store... if that doesn't help with your exact case, you might want to start a new question explaining that

Answer (score 2):

When working with custom stores it is often easiest to start from one of the 'built-ins' to get the reactivity, subscriptions and others out of the box.  And then add custom behaviour to it.

As mentioned, the issue here is the way that JavaScript works in regards to object references vs primitives. Even with a custom store, running a custom `set` will show that the *current value* of your object has already changed.

To work around this you can extend your object with a `Proxy` instead and wrap that one in a *writable* store for all the store goodness.

```js
import { get, writable } from 'svelte/store';

export default function(initial, beforeChange) {
    if (!beforeChange) {
        return writable(initial)
    }
    const handler = {
        set(obj, prop, value) {
            // Do things here
            beforeChange(obj);
            
            // default behaviour
            obj[prop] = value;
            return true;
        }
    }
    const store = writable(new Proxy(initial, handler));
    const set = (newvalue) => {
        // Circumvent the fact that get is called after every change causing  beforeChange being called twice
        const current = {...get(store)}
        if (JSON.stringify(newvalue) != JSON.stringify(current)) beforeChange(current);

        store.set(new Proxy(newvalue, handler))
    }
    
    return {
        ...store,
        set
    }
}
```

Here in this `set` function, `obj` will contain the *old values* until you explicitly change them to the new values.

In this code I added a `beforeChange` option to get a flexible solution that can be extended with the desired behaviour.

```js
const store = proxyStore({
  name: 'Stephane'
}, (old) => {
  // Do things with the old value
});
```

[Demo as REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ffb4f7fbf25f4b05ba31ac7ef96dd198?version=3.50.0)

Comment: You might also want to return a wrapped `set` function instead of the store directly, so a full store value replacement can be handled.

Comment: Good catch! Added a quick custom setter as well :)

Comment: My primary concern was that the `Proxy` will be lost, should have been more explicit.

Comment: Actually... I just tried it with the original code and everything works fine and as expected, will revert the edit and add a link to a REPL

Comment: nvm confusing myself here, tried with update not set, will have to fix this [done]

Comment: Looks better, though `beforeChange` is now called twice, because Svelte, as outlined in my answer, always calls it after properties as well. Maybe it should be omitted from the `set` function and left to the store user . Another approach might be to keep track of whether it has been called in the current event loop, though that will increase complexity and surface for bugs....

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a property, the object that the property is assigned on stays the same, the same is true for all objects. In the case of stores, the function is invoked regardless, to ensure that subscribers can be made aware of changes to the object.

If you want to be able to swap out the entire previous state, you have to reassign the entire store value (`$objectStore = ...`).

---

The compiled output is this:

```js
function input1_input_handler() {
    $objectStore.foo = this.value;
    objectStore.set($objectStore);
}
```

As you can see, the property is assigned and `set` is called for the existing object.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I compare the new value of the store to the current value before the new value is set?

Since the value binding directly changes the store object, the old state is lost. This would be an alternative way without binding but with a custom store and the update method to compare the old and new value before updating the store [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6805990cad5f42458736a3073209ea62?version=3.50.0)

```
<script>
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

    function createCustomStore(initialValue) {
        const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(initialValue);

        return {
            subscribe,
            input(event) {
                update(storeValue => {
                    console.log('current', storeValue)
                    const newFoo = event.target.value
                    storeValue.foo = newFoo
                    console.log('new', storeValue)
                    return storeValue
                })
            }
        };
    }

    const objectStore = createCustomStore({foo: "bar"});

</script>

<input type="text" value={$objectStore.foo} on:input={objectStore.input} >
```